# Using WriteConsoleOutput to write Unicode with c#

Tags: c#, windows, unicode, console

I am trying to use the `WriteConsoleOutput`function from kernel32.dll, however I cannot get unicode characters to display correctly, they always display as the wrong characters.

I have attempted to use:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Changing this to `Encoding.Unicode` does not work either.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetConsoleOutputCP(uint wCodePageID);

public void SetCP(){
   SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
}
```

I have tried using both of the above, each one individually and none with just about every combination of values.

I have also switched between all fonts (including the true type ones), however none of them seem to display the characters correctly.

Here is the code I am using to use WriteConsoleOutput

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "WriteConsoleOutputW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool WriteConsoleOutputW(SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput, CharInfo[] lpBuffer, Coord dwBufferSize, Coord dwBufferCoord, ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string fileName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare, IntPtr securityAttributes, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags, IntPtr template);

private static readonly SafeFileHandle h = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

public static void RegionWrite(string s, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{           
    if (!h.IsInvalid)
    {
        int length = width * height;

        // Pad any extra space we have
        string fill = s + new string(' ', length - s.Length);

        // Grab the background and foreground as integers
        int bg = (int) Console.BackgroundColor;
        int fg = (int) Console.ForegroundColor;

        // Make background and foreground into attribute value
        short attr = (short)(fg | (bg << 4));

        CharInfo[] buf = fill.Select(c => 
        {
            CharInfo info = new CharInfo();

            // Give it our character to write
            info.Char.UnicodeChar = c;

            // Use our attributes
            info.Attributes = attr;

            // Return info for this character
            return info;

        }).ToArray();

        // Make everything short so we don't have to cast all the time
        short sx = (short) x;
        short sy = (short) y;
        short swidth = (short) width;
        short sheight = (short) height;

        // Make a buffer size out our dimensions
        Coord bufferSize = new Coord(swidth, sheight);

        // Not really sure what this is but its probably important
        Coord pos = new Coord(0, 0);

        // Where do we place this?
        SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = sx, Top = sy, Right = (short) (sx + swidth), Bottom = (short) (sy + sheight) };

        bool b = WriteConsoleOutputW(h, buf, bufferSize, pos, ref rect);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Console handle is invalid.");
    }

}
```

Using this with standard ASCII characters works perfectly:

`RegionWrite("Hello world", 4, 4, 10, 10);`

However when I use anything above the standard ASCII range, it fails to display correctly:

`RegionWrite("┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬┬", 4, 4, 10, 10);` This outputs as two lines of ',' characters, this makes some sense as the "┬" character has a value of 9516, 9516 % 128 is 44 which is the ascii code for ','.

**I know it is physically possible to output these characters as `Console.Write("┬┬┬┬")` works correctly. I am switching from `Console.Write` to `WriteConsoleOutput` as there is a significant performance increase.**

Here is the code im using to set code pages:

```
public void Setup()
{
    Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
    Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;

    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

    DefaultColor();
    Console.Clear();

    Console.ReadLine();

    RegionWrite("┬┬┬┬", 4, 4, 10, 10);

    Console.WriteLine("┬┬┬┬");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here are my structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Coord
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;

    public Coord(short X, short Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte AsciiChar;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharInfo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public CharUnion Char;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public short Attributes;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SmallRect
{
    public short Left;
    public short Top;
    public short Right;
    public short Bottom;
}
```

I assume I have screwed up one of the variables of `WriteConsoleOutput` but after hours of searching for answers i'm really not sure where i've gone wrong. Is there some internal set encoding function I need to use?

nvm fixed it

Comment: You should be using `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;` and forget the code page.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have tried this, it makes no difference.

Comment: Well you also need to specify `Charset.Unicode` in the declaration for `CharInfo`, otherwise it will default to ANSI: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]` (and maybe in some of your other structs as well, not sure about those).

Comment: Ugh facepalm, thank you so much.

Comment: Don't post answers inside questions. If you have an answer to your question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution, change

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte AsciiChar;
}
```

to

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CharUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte AsciiChar;
}
```

This is because it will default to ANSI meaning your unicode characters get automatically turned into ANSI, hence ┬ into ,

Comment: I had to add the CharSet attribute on other methods as well (like `WriteConsoleOutput`) to make it works